# Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have code in perl module file.
When I submit the button in web, I want to call an external script perl.
Here is my code in perl module file.

```
package web::modify::send;
use strict;

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
no warnings 'redefine';<br>
sub send{
    my $s = shift;
    my $op = $s->param('Submit');
    eval {
        if ($op eq 'send') {
            system("./../bin/perl1.pl >> /log/file/perl1.log 2>&1 &");
        }
    };
    return;
}
1;
```

And i have an warning like this:

> [Mon Feb 29 11:54:38 20] [warn] Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /home/file/web/modify/send.pm line 1230.\n

Comment: Your code and the error message do not fit together. What is in line 1230? How is it invoked with the `-T` taint mode switch? Does your web server do that? The method `send` you are showing is never called in what we see here, and there is no mention of `$ENV{PATH}` in your code. There is also a `<br>` in your code, in line 4. That does not belong there. Please [edit] your question and clear it up.

Answer (score 3):

That error is one generated by "taint" mode - as you've figured out.

It alerts when the `$PATH` environment variable includes a relative path, or if the path includes things that are writable by untrusted users. That's because a *relative* path varies depending on where - and who - is running the script, and thus allows `system`  calls to be subverted....

Just like you're doing here:

```
system("./../bin/perl1.pl >> /log/file/perl1.log 2>&1 &");
```

The way to avoid this is - avoid any relative paths in `$PATH` e.g. ones not starting with `/`. And use absolute paths to any binaries you're running from within the script.

See: [`perldoc perlsec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Cleaning-Up-Your-Path)

> For "Insecure $ENV{PATH} " messages, you need to set `$ENV{'PATH'}` to a known value, and each directory in the path must be absolute and non-writable by others than its owner and group. You may be surprised to get this message even if the pathname to your executable is fully qualified. This is not generated because you didn't supply a full path to the program; instead, it's generated because you never set your PATH environment variable, or you didn't set it to something that was safe. Because Perl can't guarantee that the executable in question isn't itself going to turn around and execute some other program that is dependent on your PATH, it makes sure you set the PATH.